# How to show Excel's charts via smart devices

Tags: android, excel, business-intelligence, dashboard, dashboard-designer

I have experienced in SAP BOBJ and I knew that we can connect between smart devices (ipad,etc) and BOBJ server to show dashboards.
At present, I only used MS Excel 2013 to build dashboards and it did not use the external data.I find the solution to help my colleagues connect to this Excel file to view dashboards via smart devices especially in Android OS and iOS.
 Could you give me an advice or other ideas to solve this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Power BI app works on Android and iOS to show dashboards created with Power BI Designer and published to the Power BI service. Power BI can access a multitude of online and on-premise data sources, can use DAX on the data model and has all kinds of charts and visualisations and then some.

Comment: Thank @teylyn I knew this BI solution before. I also used Tableau and Qlik. However, I need to try with Excel 2013. Other BI solutions need to buy license. I will consider in case of free products first.

Comment: Power BI standard is free.